# Writing contents of ArrayList to a newLine

Tags: java, arraylist

I have a method which writes the elements of the array list to a file. The problem is i need a new line for the next 6 consecutive elements in the List.
So the file will look like this.

```
wrds,wrds,wrds,wrds,wrds,wrds

wrds,wrds,wrds,wrds,wrds,wrds
```

etc. so the list will look like this:

```
wrds,wrds,wrds,wrds,wrds,wrds,wrds,wrds,wrds,wrds,wrds,wrds
```

I need to split the elements by 6 and write them on a new line each time. How do i do this?

```
public void printToFile()
{
    for (int i = 0; i <= one.size(); i++) {
        try {
            output.write((String)one.get(i));
            if (i == 6) {
                output.newLine();
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace(System.err);
        }  
    }
}
```

Comment: what is the problem?

Answer (score 1):

Everything you need here is an if statement that will evaluate to `true` for 6th, 12th, 18th... etc. element. You can achieve this using modulo operator (%). `i % 6 == 0` will evaluate to true for any `i`that is a multiple of 6.